# How do I use two versions of the same javascript library without bleeding functions in the same page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a use case where I need to use multiple versions of the Nvd3 library for different charts on the same page in an angular application (Each chart is loaded through a separate template). How do I avoid such a collision?

So, let's say the graph on partial_1.html requires a v1.8, graph on partial_2.html requires v1.1 and so on. Any help would be highly appreciated.

jQuery tries to fix this using the noConflict method, but I can't seem to find a solution that works for arbitrary js libraries (not just jQuery).

Comment: My advice: upgrade the outdated chart :)

Comment: Here's another tip to avoid this in the future: always always alias all 3rd party function calls.

Comment: Upgrading the chart is not an option since the newer version of Scatterplot doesn't have the fisheye magnification for reasons beyond my comprehension and downgrading other ones is not an option because I need some of the newer versions. :) @JaredSmith What do you mean by alias third party calls? Could you give an example? :)

Comment: You could always add the fisheye yourself and not rely on nvd3.  Or you could get really crazy and drop nvd3 and just use base d3!

Comment: @Mark Time constraints wouldn't allow writing all that by myself in d3. Need to push out a variety of charts in a relatively short span of time. :)

Comment: If nvd3 supports AMD, I'd recommend you look into RequireJS  http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. For now, I ended up moving to the latest version and implementing the zoom functionality myself. Benefit: I now have zoom for all nvd3 charts out there.

Comment: Use your own abstraction layer over the third party library. Ex: if using jQuery for css selection of DOM elements like so `var elem = $('#my-element');` what happens when you decide to swap jQuery out for something else? Instead write your own function `getElem()` that takes a css selector string and passes it to the library's function. Now you can change versions/libraries without having to look through your entire codebase. Your `getElem()` function is an alias for the other, but as long as the signature doesn't change you can easily swap out the underlying function its an alias for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot update the older charts to use the most recent version, then you have only one option, and that is to rename the global variable "d3" for each version that you are using. Then, you should do a find and replace on each template to change the referenced variables. That way each points to a specific version. You could accomplish this with code that looks something like this:

```
(function (w, d) {
    "use strict";
    var h = d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        s = d.createElement("script");
    w.d3 = null;
    s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js";
    s.onload = function () {
        w.d3_3_5_3 = w.d3;
        w.d3 = undefined;
        s = d.createElement("script");
        s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.4/d3.min.js";
        s.onload = function () {
            w.d3_3_5_4 = w.d3;
            w.d3 = undefined;
            s = d.createElement("script");
            s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js";
            s.onload = function () {
                w.d3_3_5_5 = w.d3;
                w.d3 = undefined;
            };
            h.appendChild(s);
        };
        h.appendChild(s);
    };
    h.appendChild(s);
}(window, document));
```

The example above loads three versions, and by using the onload event, it captures each new instance of d3 and puts it into its own variable. In this case, d3_3_5_3, d3_3_5_4, and d3_3_5_5

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up moving to the newer version of the charts and and made my own zoom functionality using `d3.zoom()` that I can now use on any nvd3 chart. :)